# Sum of Fibonacci Sequence off by a value of 1

Tags: java, math, fibonacci

I have a code to calculate the sum of all even numbers of the Fibonacci Sequence less than 4,000,000.

```java
/*
  Through the use of Binet's formula for the Fibonacci Sequence and the fact
  that every third number of the sequence is an even number.
*/

import java.lang.Math.*;

public class Optimised002 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4_000_000; i += 3) {
      long number = binetsFormula(i);
      if (number < 4_000_000L) {
        sum += number;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
  }

  public static float sqrt5 = 2.2360679775f;
  public static float goldenRatio = 1.61803398875f;
  public static float reciprocalGoldenRaio = -0.61803398875f;

  public static long binetsFormula(int nth) {
    return Math.round((Math.pow(goldenRatio, nth) - Math.pow(reciprocalGoldenRaio, nth)) / sqrt5);
  }
}
```

The correct answer that I had obtained through bruteforce previously is 4613732, for this method I am obtaining the sum of 4613733: off by a value of 1. Maybe its because of sqrt5 or goldenRatio not being precise enough or some computers being bad at maths sort of thing: I have no idea why. Insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: @khelwood I am summing up only every third number of the Fibonacci sequence so both 1s are skipped.

Comment: Well if you were only adding even numbers there's no way you'd get an odd total. How about you check which of the terms you're adding is odd?

Comment: @khelwood that is a good point

Comment: I would recommend using `double`, not `float`.  You've shown those constants to more decimal places than a `float` can represent accurately, and Binet's formula is actually quite sensitive to inaccuracies in the values of these constants.

Comment: Reminder: real-world arithmetic and computer arithmetic are not the same thing.

Comment: Another wee problem with your code - you're only adding up 11 Fibonacci numbers, but you're calculating 1.33 million of them, and just throwing away the result for most of them.  That means your code is 120k times slower than it needs to be.

Comment: And lastly, I don't think the `- Math.pow(reciprocalGoldenRaio, nth)` part is going to change the result at all.  That term gets really small really fast, and your rounding will kill it completely anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the floats to doubles and also use the built-in Math class.

I think that double can store more decimals than float, since double stores 64 bits of information whereas float stores 32 bits of information.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

It is also the case that the static method Math.sqrt(n) returns a double, so it makes sense to use double.

Here is a code example.

```
public class BinetsFormula {
  
    public int fib(int n) {
        double a = (1 + Math.sqrt(5))/2;
        double b = (1 - Math.sqrt(5))/2;
        double c = (Math.pow(a, n) - Math.pow(b, n))/Math.sqrt(5);
        return (int) c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinetsFormula formula = new BinetsFormula();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (i < 19)
                System.out.print(formula.fib(i) + " ");
            else if (i == 19) 
                System.out.println(formula.fib(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The above code prints out the first 20 fibonacci numbers.

Now we can get the sum of all even fibonacci numbers less than 4,000,000.

```
public class BinetsFormula {
 
    private final double sqrt5 = Math.sqrt(5);
    private final double a = (1 + sqrt5)/2;
    private final double b = (1 - sqrt5)/2;

    public long fib(int n) {
        return Math.round((Math.pow(a, n) - Math.pow(b, n))/sqrt5);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinetsFormula formula = new BinetsFormula();
        int n = 0;
        long f = 0;
        long sum = 0;
        long max = 4000000;
        while ((f = formula.fib(n)) < max) {
            if (f % 2 == 0)
                sum += f;
            n++;
        }
        System.out.printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
    }
}
```

The second example is optimized.

I created the constants sqrt5, a, and b so that these computations are only performed once.